# How to check whether all transactions in the loop(cursors) are success or not in sql?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am using cursor to delete set of tables.  I need to set flag to identify whether all transactions are success or not. Can you please give me some sample queries?

```
DEclare @intErrorCode int;
DECLARE @TblName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE TBL_Cursor CURSOR
FOR ( select name from sysobjects where name like 'tbl_flat%');
OPEN TBL_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_Cursor INTO @TblName
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
IF LEN(@TblName) >0
BEGIN
DECLARE @strsql nvarchar(max)
BEGIN
     something here
        BEGIN TRAN
        EXEC sp_executesql @strsql
        COMMIT TRAN
        SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
        IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

END
END
FETCH NEXT FROM TBL_Cursor INTO @TblName
END

 CLOSE TBL_Cursor
 DEALLOCATE TBL_Cursor
PROBLEM:
 IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) BEGIN
 PRINT 'Unexpected error occurred!'
  END
```

Comment: @jeremy This cursor actually deletes some set of tables. Do you have any idea to get success or failure flag once all transaction is done?

Comment: try/catch is the usual method for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        --your code
    EXEC sp_executesql @strsql
    COMMIT TRAN -- Transaction Success!
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN --RollBack in case of Error
    -- you can Raise ERROR with RAISEERROR() Statement including the details of the exception
    RAISERROR(ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), 1)
END CATCH
```